# Return indexes of greatest value in a 3 dimensional array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of this:

```
[34, 12, 56]
[100,125,19]
[30,50,69]
```

125 has been the highest value, it will return the index [1,1] format. Meaning 125 which is the highest value will return row 1 column 1

I was able to get the index in an array using this code

```
var a = [0, 21, 22, 7, 12];
var indexOfMaxValue = a.reduce((iMax, x, i, arr) => x > arr[iMax] ? i : 
iMax, 0);
document.write("indexOfMaxValue = " + indexOfMaxValue); // prints 
"indexOfMaxValue = 2"
```

Comment: That's not 3 dimensional - only 2d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my approach. It flattens out all the arrays into more managable one, finds the max number and its index, and then calculates it's position using some math. Using a single array makes this calculation much easier.

```js
const arr = [[34, 12, 56], [100,125,19], [30,50,69]];
const arr2 = [0, 21, 22, 7, 12];

function findHighest(arr) {

  // Get the number of columns
  const cols = arr.length;

  // Flatten out the arrays
  const tempArr = arr.flatMap(el => el);

  // Get the max number from the array
  const max = Math.max.apply(null, tempArr);

  // Find its index
  const indexMax = tempArr.findIndex(el => el === max);

  // Find the remainder (modulo) when you divide the index
  // by the number of columns
  const mod = indexMax % cols;

  // Return the final array output
  return [Math.floor(indexMax / cols), mod];
}

console.log(findHighest(arr))
console.log(findHighest(arr2))
```

Comment: Pretty sweet solution, but have in mind if the array's arent the same length this might break

Comment: That's a fair point @SimonDragsbæk, but sometimes you just have to go with the limited information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the expected output but not sure is it good way to solve this:

```
var arr = [
    [34, 12, 56],
    [100, 125, 19],
    [30, 50, 69]
];
var maxValue, maxIndex;
arr.forEach((arr1, i) => {
    arr1.forEach((value, j) => {
        if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
            maxValue = value;
            maxIndex = [i, j]
        } else {
            if (maxValue < value) {
                maxValue = value;
                maxIndex = [i, j];
            }

        }

    });
});

console.log("Max Number Index", maxIndex);
```

Comment: This doesn't care about the array lengths it just finds the highest value

Comment: You __can't__ just edit the question to fit your answer. That's not how this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 2d solution, try this. Should work for dynamic length arrays
This should be extendable with a new forEach for a new dimension

```
[100,125,19],
[30,50,69]];

maxIndex = [-1, -1];
maxElem = 0;
input.forEach(function(arr, row) {
    console.error(row);
    arr.forEach(function(e, col) {
    if( maxElem <= e ) {
        maxElem = e;
        maxIndex = [row, col];
    }
  })
})

console.log(maxIndex)
```

Comment: ```Array.map``` will iterate the array but I guess ```for/forEach``` sustainable for iteration not ```Array.map```